# Given two lat/long/altitude points, how do I find the north/east/up vector between the two points?

Tags: geometry

I have two lat/long/altitude points $(\phi_1,\lambda_1,h_1)$ and $(\phi_2,\lambda_2,h_2)$. I wanted to find the distances in the east and north directions (up is fairly obvious, I think?) between these two points. The points are relatively close together (same geographical region). Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: The details of this are typically part of GIS. The Earth (for a few reasons) is not a sphere, but an oblate spheroid. IIRC, errors of 1-3% in distance can crop up if the oblateness is not included in the calculations.

Comment: Do you want a straight line ignoring the solid earth, or a great circle with a gradual altitude shift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a spherical earth, north is just $R_e(\phi_1-\phi_2)\frac \pi{180}$, where $R_e$ is the earth radius and the $\frac \pi{180}$ comes from measuring latitude in degrees.  For east, you have to determine which line of latitude you will measure along, as it gets shorter as you get near the poles.  I will use the average latitude.  If $\phi_1 \approx \phi_2$ it won't matter much.  The value is $R_e (\lambda_1-\lambda_2) \frac \pi{180}\cos \left(\frac {\phi_1+\phi_2}2\right)$ where you have to work out the sign depending on which hemisphere you are in.